# Openimaj supports gpgpu?

Tags: video-processing, gpgpu, openimaj

I can see OpenImaj use OpenCL in its code. But I can't find any information in the documentation and in google about OpenImaj support GPGPU.

I'm confused. Did OpenImaj use GPU acceleration?

If yes, why doesn't indicate in its documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that exist a plan to support GPGPU, but any progress since 2016.

https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/blob/6da5e28982ee05f6b26ece8c3d58c60860c3cd21/hardware/core-gpgpu/README